# AS400 SQL query similar to CLRLIB (clear library) in native AS400

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I'm working on a AS400 database and I need to manipulate library/collection with sql.

I need to recreate something similar to the CLRLIB command but I don't find a good way to do this.

Is there a way to delete all the table from a library with a sql query ?

Maybe I can drop the collection and create a new one with the same name. But I don't know if this is a good way to clear the library.

RESOLVE :
Thanks to Buck Calabro for his solution.

I use the following query to call the CLRLIB in SQL :

```
CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC('CLRLIB LIB_NAME ASPDEV(ASP_NAME)', 0000000032.00000)
```

Where LIB_NAME is the name of the library I want to clear, ASP_NAME is the name of the ASP where the library is and 0000000032.00000 is the command lenght.

Comment: Why do you need to do this chore 'the SQL way'?  Why isn't CLRLIB sufficient?

Comment: I work with a BPM software (Bonita BPM) and to interact with the database it use a AS400 connector with sql queries.
I cannot use the command CLRLIB in a sql query.

Comment: You can CALL QCMDEXC as a stored procedure and execute a CL command that way.

Answer (score 2):

(note that the term COLLECTION has been deprecated, SCHEMA is the current term)

Since a library can contain both SQL and non-SQL objects, there's no SQL way to delete every possible object type.

Dropping the schema and recreating it might work.  But note that if the library is in a job's library list, it will have a lock on it and you will not be able to drop it.  Also, unless the library was originally created via CREATE SCHEMA (or CREATE COLLECTION) you're going to end up with differences.

CRTLIB creates an empty library, CREATE SCHEMA creates a library plus objects needed for automatic journaling and a dozen or so SQL system views.

Answer (score 1):

Read Charles' answer - there may be objects in your schema that you want to keep (data areas, programs, display and printer files, etc.)  If the problem is to delete all of the tables so you can re-build all of the tables, then look at the various system catalog tables: SYSTABLES, SYSVIEWS, SYSINDEXES, etc.  The system catalog 'knows' about all of the SQL tables, indexes, views, stored procedures, triggers and so on.  You could read the catalog and issue the appropriate SQL DROP statements.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will look what I can do with the SYSTABLES catalog.